# Writing HTML tags in react and flux

Tags: html, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am teaching myself REACT/FLUX frameworks.I have this html section.

```
<article class="column_grid_5 " data-id="2">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <hgroup>
            <h1><a href="#">13</a></h1>
            <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
        </hgroup>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>cube</h3>

                    <strong>R1.90</strong>

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="quantity_single">
                    <label>qty</label>
                </li>
                <li class="second">
                    <h3>Pkt</h3>

                    <strong>R9.06</strong>

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="quantity_case">
                    <label>qty</label>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="button detail">Details</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button">
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
```

I have all other code sections working fine.I would like to render the above code using this render function.I am however, having trouble with my render function

```
        render: function() {
            var e = this.state.inBasket ? "is-inBasket " : "",
                t = {
                    transitionDelay: .25 * this.props.index + "s"
                };
            return n.createElement("article", {
                style: t,
                className: "column_grid_5"
            }, n.createElement("div", {
                className: "appItem appItem--" + e
            }, n.createElement("h4", {
                className: "appItem-title truncate"
            }, n.createElement("div", {
                className: "image"
            }, this.props.item.name), n.createElement("img", {
                className: "",
                src: this.props.item.image,
                alt: ""
            }), n.createElement("hgroup", {
                className: ""
            }, this.props.item.name), n.createElement("h2", {
                className: ""
            }), n.createElement("div", {
                className: "appItem-price"
            }, "$ ", this.props.item.price, ".00"), n.createElement("div", {
                className: "appItem-qty"
            }, "x ", this.props.item.qty), n.createElement("div", {
                className: "basketControls"
            }, this.getBasketControls()))))
        }
```

I am getting this output:

```
<article style="transition-delay:0s;" class="column_grid_5 itemTransition-enter itemTransition-enter-active" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0"><div class="appItem appItem--" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0"><h4 class="appItem-title truncate" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0"><div class="image" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.0">Title</div><img class="" src="images/white/1.jpg" alt="" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.1"><hgroup class="" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.2">Title</hgroup></h4><h2 class="" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.3"></h2><div class="appItem-price" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.4"><span data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.4.0">$ </span><span data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.4.1">21</span><span data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.4.2">.00</span></div><div class="appItem-qty" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.5"><span data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.5.0">x </span></div><div class="basketControls" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.6"><button class="addBasket button" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.2.0.1.$=1$white:0.0.1.$=1$1:0.0.0.6.0">Add to basket</button></div></div></article>
```

Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated

Comment: Do you not want to use `jsx` or are you not aware that you can put straight HTML in your render function?

Comment: ^ this.  You can copy/paste your entire HTML in your React component, and change a few JSX-specific things.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html#jsx-syntax

Comment: @Gregg i would surely want to use JSX if appropriate.How do i then go about it

Comment: @MichaelParker I have everything in place,what you are asking will require that i re-write my code. - i am looking at simple createElement and className scenarios as i am not able to have elements arranged as in the first html code in my question

Comment: ... no it won't.  JSX is literally HTML with a few of the attributes changed.  In other words, copy and paste your HTML, replace all `class` with `className`, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using JSX for this. Example:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <article class="column_grid_5 " data-id="2">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <hgroup>
            <h1><a href="#">13</a></h1>
            <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
        </hgroup>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h3>cube</h3>

                    <strong>R1.90</strong>

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="quantity_single">
                    <label>qty</label>
                </li>
                <li class="second">
                    <h3>Pkt</h3>

                    <strong>R9.06</strong>

                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="quantity_case">
                    <label>qty</label>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="button detail">Details</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button">
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
  );
}
```

I literally copied the HTML you provided and assuming the HTML is valid, this will work. Now, all you need to work out is getting the data into your HTML from state and/or props.

Comment: I am using this http://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm i am however getting syntax error

Comment: What error are you getting? I can't read your screen from here. ;)

Comment: I am getting this build.js:13572 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  line 13572 in build.js has <article className="column_grid_5 " data-id={2}>

Comment: What build system are you using? Does it know how to compile JSX? There's a lot of missing details which makes it impossible to solve your problem. It might be time to start a new question now that I've moved into using JSX.